# Does performance decrease / memory use increase if your class gains more methods

Tags: javascript, php, performance, oop, memory

Does every instance of that class need more memory because it will inherrit its own copy of the method? Or do only instance properties (data) improve memory use.

And is the answer generally speaking the same in PHP and javascript? Or do they differ in how this works?

Comment: as far as I know, methods are not part of block occupied in memory for an object instance, only data-properties. This can be checked with a simple sizeOf(). But that is so with compiled languages. As for interpreted run-time languages like php and javascript I dont know.

Comment: The term *inherit* implies that they don't have their own, but share a method with other instances. Only if you explicitly *copy* a method onto the instance, it will need additional memory.

Answer (score 3):

In PHP, there is only ever one copy of the code (methods) for a class in memory, no matter how many instances there may be.... static attributes also only exist once in memory; but all non-static attributes are in memory for every instance of that class

Comment: Any proof on PHP object internal representation?

Comment: There's some information [here](https://gist.github.com/nikic/5015323) on the internal representation of objects in PHP